# Virtualbox image corrupted on vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I've been having some trouble with Vagrant and Virtualbox lately and I can't pinpoint what is going on. I am trying to use the Vagrant setup in this repository (https://github.com/sapienza/vagrant-php-box) but everytime I issue a `vagrant up` command I get the same traceback error about a corrupted image:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/home/dan/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20160602.0.0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1466024621846_36463", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "6", "--disk", "/home/dan/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1466024621846_36463/box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /home/dan/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20160602.0.0/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the imported medium '/home/dan/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1466024621846_36463/box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: Compressed image is corrupted '/home/dan/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20160602.0.0/virtualbox/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 877 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

I attempted to remove the corrupted box with `vagrant box remove ubuntu/trusty64` and reissue the `vagrant up` command and the box appears to be successfully downloaded but it fails every time when importing the base box.

I'm currently using Vagrant 1.8.4 and Virtualbox 5.0.20 on Ubuntu 14.04. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you delete `/home/dan/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64` and `/home/dan/.vagrant.d/tmp` and then retry

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I removed the directories as you said and get the same error. It appears to occur whenever I download a fresh box as if the source is corrupted from the start or something in the toolchain is not finishing the download correctly.

Comment: Had a same problem here. Deleted `VirtualBox VMs` and `.vagrant.d` from my home on Ubuntu 16.04 and restarted `vagrant up`. This time it worked perfectly. I believe the image was downloaded corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

To assist in the troubleshooting, how about:

1. Create a new directory
2. Inside the new directory, execute a `vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64`
3. vagrant up

Does the machine come up ? if so, then environment should be okay.

Next I would create a new directory again, and copy only the relevant files from that github repo excluding the hidden directory `.vagrant`

Ideally, a .gitignore should be in present in that repo excluding that a .vagrant directory.

Good Luck!

Comment: I attempted what you said and have the same corrupted error from before.